# textFont not working in p5.js, I am not even getting any errors

Tags: javascript, html, fonts, p5.js

I am writing a code in p5js that should change the text font but its not working. The following are my codes

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coiny" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
<script>
function draw() 
  {
    createCanvas(200, 200);
    noLoop();
    background(30);
    fill(125,200,25);
    textSize(40);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    textFont("Coiny");
    text("The Text", 100,100);
  }
</script>
```

I can't figure out where I am wrong as I am not getting any errors in the console window.
I got the codes from [here](https://editor.p5js.org/runemadsen/sketches/SJ5iB4Q3-). Can anyone please tell me where am I going wrong and correct me?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I guess I have found the error, there are a few commands that don't work if I use `noLoop()`. In the following, I removed the `noLoop()`:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coiny" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function draw() {
    createCanvas(200, 200);
    background(30);
    fill(125, 200, 25);
    textSize(40);
    textAlign(CENTER);
    textFont("Coiny");
    text("The Text", 100, 100);
  }
</script>
```

See?
Now my problem is how to do it with a noLoop in the code.. or may be solving this one may also help me. [My other question, closely related to this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65589939/ably-not-working-in-draw-function-p5-js)

Comment: That font is set up to use specific Unicode ranges for different language environments.